# How to get referrer from playstore to app using Play Install Referrer Library?

Tags: android

I want to get referrer query parameter from google play url inside my app.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<apppid>&referrer=myReferrerValue
```

i wrote this

```
InstallReferrerClient referrerClient;

referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build();
referrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
        switch (responseCode) {
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK:
                Log.d("InstallReferrerResponse","Connection established");

                ReferrerDetails response = null;
                try {
                    response = referrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
                    String referrerUrl = response.getInstallReferrer();

                    Log.d("InstallReferrerResponse",referrerUrl);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                Log.d("InstallReferrerResponse","API not available on the current Play Store app");
                break;
            case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("InstallReferrerResponse","Connection couldn't be established");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
    }
});
```

but i am only getting `utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic` not getting referrer=myReferrerValue.

how to get referrer=myReferrerValue ?